# Ajax.Begin Form client side validation in Partial View MVC5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="search-ctn">
    @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Home.Search()); }
</div>
```

Search.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModels.SearchVM

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Home.Search(), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "idx-list-ctn", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @id = "sch-frm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Service)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Service)
}
```

MVC.Home.Search Action:

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual PartialViewResult Search(SearchVM partnerSearch)
    {
       // Search made here
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SearchVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Service { get; set; }
}
```

Libraries:

```
jquery-2.1.3.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js (v3.2.3)
jquery.validate.js (v1.13.1)
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (v3.2.3)
```

In an old project using jquery-1.10.2.js I was activating the form's validation like this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.addValidation("#sch-frm");
```

and it was working just fine, but now it's submiting the form ignoring the validation.

Comment: Since your using `Html.Action()` to to include the partial in the Index view (i.e. its not content that added dynamically after the page has been rendered) then doing anything with the validator is not necessary (and should never have been, suggesting you have other problems). What is `MVC.Home.Search()`? - you should not have a method inside a helper. What is `.addValidation("#form");`? and what is `#form'? - you don't have an element with `id="form"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. The form simply submits and don't present any Validation error message. MVC.Search is an action that performs the search (I will update the question with it). The form id is "sch-form" let me correct, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Again - what is `MVC.Home.Search()` and what is `.addValidation()`? And why do you have the model in the view as `SearchVM` but post back to `PartnerSearchVM`?

Comment: Hi, the MVC.Home.Search is the Action name from the question (I use T4MVC plug-in to avoid strings) and addValidation from this post: http://www.mfranc.com/javascript/unobtrusive-validation-in-partial-views/ to be able to validate a form in a PartialView. Sorry for the mistake, I have corrected the post back to SearchVM

Comment: You only need to re-parse the validator when you add dynamic content after the page has been rendered. `RenderAction` add the partial view as part of the view so your `addValidation` is not required (and never was)

Comment: I have already tried to parse the form with $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#sch-frm"); but it's still not working

Comment: I repeat, you are not adding dynamic content so you do **not** need to parse the form again. What ever problems your having with client side validation have nothing to do with the code you have shown here.